# Mousedown not working with vis timeline

Tags: jquery, timeline, clickable, mousedown

I have a problem with mousedown event join to a vis timeline map...

This is the structure of my code :

```
<div id="firstDiv">
   <div id="timelineMap"></div>
</div>

$("#firstDiv").mousedown(function (e) {
    console.log("mouseDown");

    initialW = e.pageX;
    initialH = e.pageY;

    $("#firstDiv").bind("mouseup", function1);
    $("#firstDiv").bind("mousemove", function2);
    }
});
```

But when I click on the firstDiv nothing is happening. I think that the problem is inside the timelineMap because without it `mousedown` works... inside that div there is the vis timeline map. The strange thing is that if I use `click()` instead of `mousedown` it works but obviously in that case I can't use `mouseup`.

Please help me to figure out

Comment: Don't use deprecated function `bind`, and don't use nested events (attach event inside event).

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki Said was right. Use new method `jQuery.on()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

> As of jQuery 3.0, .bind() has been deprecated. It was superseded by the .on() method for attaching event handlers to a document since jQuery 1.7, so its use was already discouraged.

Try to use **[`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** instead :

```
$("#firstDiv").on('mousedown', function (e) {
    console.log("mouseDown");
    initialW = e.pageX;
    initialH = e.pageY;
});

$("#firstDiv").on("mouseup", function1);
$("#firstDiv").on("mousemove", function2);
```

**NOTE :** You've an extra `}` in your posted code.

Hope this help.

Comment: thank you for the answer...i tried to change how you have suggested but mousedown doesn't work yet...the problem have to be bound to the vis timeline because when i hide it from the div timelineMap everything works fine